# How to tie a tie?

Tags: clothing

Most common method of tying a tie have [over 10 steps of knot tying instructions](http://www.ties.com/how-to-tie-a-tie/windsor). It's ridiculously difficult to remember it, especially if you're tying your tie very rarely.

Are there any easily rememberable life hacks to tie a tie?

[image: How to Tie a Tie]

Comment: 1) Just sit down and practice one day, it isn't that hard. 2) Tie it once, leave it tied on a hangar if used very infrequently. Most knots allow you to loosen it enough to take it off without untying. 3) Those "10 steps" are extremely basic, and similar instructions for tying shoelaces would be just as long or longer.

Comment: Adding to Geobits's comment: Instructions for tying shoelaces would be just as long or longer, but we don't forget how to tie our shoelaces. Why? It's because we tie our shoelaces very often. Get into the habit of wearing a tie frequently, and you'll never forget how to tie a tie.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to me this question is looking for a simple way to tie a tie, yet is shows the "Windsor Knot" with the example image. This is a difficult knot to tie in the first place.

I suggest going down a notch or two in styles of knot, and go for the simpler "Regular Knot. It has 3 basic steps:

- Do a 360 around the thin half of the tie with the thicker portion
- Wrap it under then over the knot
- Tuck it within the overlapped section.

#### Here is an image to demonstrate:

[image]

I tie all of my neckties like this and it takes me longer to button my shirt than it does to tie this knot.

Answer (score 3):

There is a "ninja" knot-tying skill demonstrated by [CrazyRussianHacker](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJ8CZzbIDf8) user on his video.

Here are the simple steps:

1. Put the tie on the table with thick side to your right and the thin side to your left.

   [image: step 1]
2. Twist both endings to make a loop.

   [image: step 2]
3. (tricky part) Grab the loop from your left (thin side), twist it and put it under the right loop

   [image: step 3a]

   [image: step 3b]
4. Now grab the shorter side and put it through both loops way down next to thick side.

   [image: step 4]
5. Grab the main looped part and pull it on both sides. Adjust it based on your needs.

   [image: step 5a]

   [image: step 5b]

Done.

[image: result]

It needs some practise, but once you get use to it, you'll be amazed with the results. If few years old kids can do it, you can do it either!

Comment: This just looks more complicated than tying a tie normally...

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to tie a tie. The "simplest" tie knot imo would be the 4 in hand knot. They're not recommended on spread collared shirts because the finished knot isnt wide like the full windsor. Great resource here: http://www.ties.com/how-to-tie-a-tie/four-in-hand

Comment: Could you please explain the 4 in hand knot? Links can die, so if you could explain that knot on your actual answer, that will prevent the problem of the link becoming dead.

Answer (score 1):

Follow above directions for either the windsor or regular.  Have someone lift your collar and snip the back of the tie.   Attach (glue or sew) velcro to the back so you can now attach the tie without untying and tying it again.  Will be perfect every time and quick, quick, quick.   Some will call this cheating, but no one else but you needs to know.